# Find and replace multi-line block in multiple files (bash/linux)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find-and-replace, awk

I'm trying to find a way to find a text block that meets the criteria:

1. block starts with "google = {"
2. block ends with next "}" character found - ignoring everything else.

Example

```
google = {
  block of text with some var = "value" assignments
  usually 1-3 lines of code here.
  often includes special chars like / " > < = 
}
```

Replace to specific block:

```
google = {
  source  = "hashicorp/google"
  version = ">= 4.0.0, <5.0.0"
}
```

for all files called versions.tf in all subdirectories (multiple files).

I was able to find a specific block with sed for a single file:

```
$ sed -e '/google = {/,/}/!d' versions.tf

google = {
  source  = "hashicorp/google"
  version = ">= 3.32, <4.0.0"
}
```

But I'm having hard time modify it to work recursively and replace the found block with other, fixed value.

Other approach with perl seems to do the trick for single file:

```
perl -i~ -0777 -pe 's/google = \{[^\}]+"/google = {\n      source  = \"hashicorp\/google\"\n      version = \">= 4.0.0, <5.0.0\"\n    }/g' versions.tf
```

Not the most pretty solution though ;)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something, please share it with us, otherwise it is likely that this question is closed due to lack of work from the original poster.

Comment: hi @DarkDiamond you are absolutely right. I updated my original question with my current progress. thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Have you looked for other approaches than plain regex, such as loading the file into an actual HCL parser?

Comment: No, didn't think of it. thanks for the idea, I will look into that.

Comment: Well done, this question looks way better now. Unfortunately I cannot help you with your actual problem, but hopefully someone else here can.